# Windows 8 DX11.1 exit app and return to desktop

Tags: api, winapi, windows-8, desktop

I'm developing a DirectX 11.1/Windows 8 application, and when I tell it to exit, it always returns to the start menu/modern/metro interface.  Is it possible to force it to exit and go to the desktop.  This isn't trivial, but while I'm developing, it's somewhat annoying to have to keep switching the interface after exiting.

For code, I have a seal ref class that extends Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkView, and just exit my loop in the ::Run()

I'm assuming I need to put some code into ::Uninitialize(), but I so far have not found anything on MSDN.